# Try to pass array of objects from controller to view via ViewData

Tags: javascript, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am constructing an array of objects in the controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexJson()
{
    Object[] obj = {
        new { data= "id", name= "Id" },
        new { data= "code", name= "Code" },
    };
    string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    ViewData["TableColumns"] = data;
    return View("IndexJson");
}
```

And in IndexJson.cshtml am trying to console log:

```
console.log('@ViewData["TableColumns"]')
```

And I get:

```
'[{&quot;data&quot;:&quot;id&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Id&quot;},{&quot;data&quot;:&quot;code&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Code&quot;}]'
```

How can I get an array the array objects in the IndexJson view ?

Comment: Do you want to pass the json string to javascript?

Comment: I want to get this array of objects in the view, what is the correct way ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to figout a way to pass json string/object from Controller to View then you already done, and the next is doing the convert/decode/format.

If your ultimate goal is passing data to View, then I recommend you creating a corresponding model for your object instead of passing a json string to the view. This will help expanding your app, and is benefit for maintenance(recode comment/note, update/add/delete property...). Here's my code.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
    //Object[] obj = { 
    //  new { data = "id", name = "Id" },
    //  new { data = "code", name = "Code" } 
    //};
    List<UserModel> list = new List<UserModel> { 
        new UserModel{ data = "id", name = "Id"},
        new UserModel{data = "code", name = "Code"}
    };
    ViewData["TableColumns"] = list;
    return View();
}

public class UserModel
{
    public string? data { get; set; }
    public string? name { get; set; }
}

<table>
    @{
        var list = ViewData["TableColumns"] as List<UserModel>;
        if (list != null)
        {
            @foreach (var item in list )
            {
               <tr>
                   <td>@item.name</td>
                   <td>@item.data</td>
               </tr>     
            }
        }
    }
</table>
```